# Android Fragments and Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

referring at the diagram below:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Could someone please please explain why Google suggests to use 2 separate activities on a Phone and a single activity on a Tablet?
If I have code in activity A to manage Fragment B (for a Tablet) why should I repeat the same code in Activity B for a phone?

It seems that for a Phone I can still use 1 activity as well (only activity A) and replace fragments, this could reduce redundant code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you mean..

You could use a fragment container and replace the fragments, define interface for selection callback. Google just does it this way maybe its clearer for those who come from the activities world i guess.

Comment: That's what meant, but any other advantage? Is it wrong to use a single activity and fragment manager to swap fragment on a Phone / single layout?

Comment: I believe its not wrong. I don't think there will be any advantages except that you can do it in one less activity, infact doing it in one activity its cleaner also.. depends on the actual logic implementation.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, it's cleaner, less code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, essentially, that phones are small. Really small. Tiny, in fact.

Take the classic scenario of an email application. The two fragments in that scenario would be the Message List (Fragment A) and Message Content (Fragment B). On a tablet, where you've got space, you can combine them into a single activity, concurrently on screen, comfortably. On a phone, however, you need to carefully manage your screen real estate, so you should split them into the choose-a-message phase (Activity A showing Fragment A) and the read-a-message phase (Activity B showing Fragment B).

By developing them as fragments, similar to user controls in other platforms, you can use the same fragments in the same codebase on a tablet and a phone, composing the activity from existing fragments.

Comment: Not what I've asked. I understand Fragments and Activities but why shouldn't I use a single activity with a FragmentManager to swap fragment on a phone and instead Google suggest to implement another activity B?

Comment: Oh, I see. You'll be swapping some redundant Activity logic with some unnecessary Fragment-management logic then, won't you? I don't know which is better. Logically, the "choose-and-read" activity is distinct from the "choose" and "read" activities, isn't it? You can replace any navigation between activities with in-activity fragment-switching, but why should you?

Answer (score 0):

Rejinderi's solution should work. I think that either that implementation or the one from Google's example can be a reasonable choice. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Personally, I prefer Google's example for the following reasons:

1. Separate activities means you use the activity back stack. In some (most?) cases, the fragment back stack is fine, but the default transition is different. You may prefer one over the other for UX reasons.
2. If you want to capture an intent, it may be unclear why `ActivityA` is capturing **JobB**.
3. In my experience, the logic for handling `FragmentB` without `FragmentA` is (a bit) different, and breaking it into it's own activity helps separate that logic, and makes everything more readable.
4. Menu options may also change. Again I find the separation of logic more clear.